# jquery change event callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-callback

How to call a function once after `change()` event complete?

for example, something like this: ( I know jQuery Doesn't have callback method as default )

```
$('#element').change( function(){
                     // do something on change
                     // $('#milestonesSelect').multiselect({ minWidth: 120 , height : '200px' ,selectedList: 4  }).multiselectfilter();
                      // some animation calls ...
                      // ...
                     }, function(){
                     // do something after complete
                      alert('another codes has completed when i called');
                     }
                   );
```

Is it possible to call a single callback after all the codes on change method done, except call a complete callback for every functions on it?

I need to do something after the change event has completed

Shall I need to set order to methods in change handler?

Comment: Just run your code inside that change event. There's no callback needed.

Comment: By 'do something after complete' do you mean once the first function has finished, or after the `change` event has completed?

Comment: after the change event has completed

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can probably make use of [event bubbling](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-flow-bubbling) and register a callback in the `document`.

```
$(document).on('change', '#element', function(){
    console.log('after all callbacks')
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/rtK7s/)

Comment: And what if your events are already triggered in this way? ie. `jQuery('#myelement').on('change', 'select,input', function(){ ... do stuff });` How would you attach a callback after these changes are triggered?

Comment: event bubbling link is not working in your answer. Please update for later use.

Answer (score 2):

I just spent some time exploring this myself, and decided to submit my answer to this question as well.  This is not utilizing any of jQuery's deferred methods, which might be a better approach.  I haven't explored them enough to have an opinion on the matter.

```js
$("#element").change(function() {
  handler().after(callBack($("#element").val()));
}

function handler() {
  alert("Event handler");
}

function callBack(foo) {
  alert(foo);
}
```

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/chewbakartik/9EM24/4/)

Comment: handler().after() is undefined

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, this will execute code only one time after a change event is fired:

```
var changed = false;

$('#element').on('change', function() {
    if ( !changed ) {
        // do something on change
        changed = true;
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: as you said `this will execute code only one time after a change event is fired` but I need to do something after event completed not fired. I don't want to do it at the same time with another executions